# UITextField padding

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, alignment, padding

Im having trouble creating padding for `leftView` property of `UITextField`. The code I have now creates padding for the text which is nice, but I need it for the imageView.

**UITextField Subclass method:**

- Notice `x` position of `paddingView` frame doesn't extend view to the right like expected.

  ```
  func setLeftView(imageView: UIImageView, withPadding padding: CGFloat) {

  let height = imageView.frame.height
  let width = imageView.frame.width + padding

  let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 36, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
  paddingView.addSubview(imageView)
  self.leftView = paddingView
  self.leftViewMode = .always
  }
  ```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: So you want padding for search icon ?

Comment: @technerd Yeah. I thought making the `x` value of the `paddingView`'s frame would do this but it doesn't.

Comment: Try to set `x` position of `Imageview` frame instead of `paddingView`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make changes in your function, just set frame of `imageView` and set `paddingView's` **X** position to **0**

```
func setLeftView(imageView: UIImageView, withPadding padding: CGFloat) {

let height = imageView.frame.height
let width = imageView.frame.width + padding

// Set  x position to 0
let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))

/// You need to set frame of imageView so put this line
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: padding, y: 0, width: imageView.frame.width, height: height)

paddingView.addSubview(imageView)
self.leftView = paddingView
self.leftViewMode = .always
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to override: 
override func leftViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect